# Is the Thule Subterra Backpack side access laptop pocket a problem for theft?

Tags: luggage, security, backpacks

I need a new backpack for everyday life and occasional work-related traveling. I have decided to try [Thule Subterra 30 l](https://www.thule.com/en-us/backpacks/laptop-backpacks/thule-subterra-backpack-30l-_-3204053). However, I have mixed feelings about it. Especially about that side access to the laptop packet. It feels like an easy access for thieves. The packet for tablets looks also quite unsafe.

Is there anyone with an experience with such types of backpacks? Especially with backpacks having side access to laptop packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no guarantees in life, but I have used a Crumpler ["Strictly Business"](https://www.davidjones.com/product/crumpler-strictly-business-backpack-23984006) backpack for some years now, which has a similar laptop side-access pocket, and it's never been a problem for me.  The thing, it seems to me, is that the zip is right up against the body (as it is with your Thule backpack).  It's certainly possible that someone could get that far into my personal space, unzip the zipper, and work the laptop out, but it's not happened yet.

It probably also helps that I feel quite strongly that wearing a backpack on crowded public transport is *extremely* antisocial, so I generally take it off and put it on the floor between my legs when, eg, [standing on the Northern Line](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/07/08/18/2A58E91700000578-3153549-Crammed_Commuters_queue_to_get_onto_a_Victoria_line_train_this_e-a-67_1436377260664.jpg) of a morning.

Comment: Even when not crowded, too many people wearing backpacks do not notice how every move will throw their backpack in the face of someone else :-(

Comment: Agreed; I think it's really rude.  Being a fairly large (fat) bloke, I tend to take the line that if someone's assuming their backpack takes up no space, I'll assume the same, and occupy the space that currently has their backpack in as and when I need it.  If that causes them to be jostled, well, tough.